# Setting multi string variables while having them all apply the same (python)

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm new to programming and I need some help for a ai robot I just started on
Here is my code:

```
    complements = "nice" and "happy" and "good" and "smart" and "wonderful"
    var = "You are a "+ complements
    input = raw_input

   if var in input:
        print "Thank you!"
   else:
        print "Wuhhhhh?"
```

If I type in something other than "nice" it goes to the else statement.
Or statements don't work

Comment: `input = raw_input()` [with the `()`]

Comment: Also, complements should be a list: `["nice", "happy"]`. Please do read about python lists, inputs and if statements. It seems as if you have some fundamental semantics misunderstandings that you should correct as soon as possible

Comment: what are you trying to acheive. please provide Expected out put

Comment: I was planning on changing the strings, but first I wanted to get the code done.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `and` keyword does not do what you want. It is used as a binary comparison. Due to the inner workings of Python, your variable `complements` will receive the value `"wonderful"`. You want to put these words in a list (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)). You will then be able to manipulate these words using concatenation as such (for example):

```
var = "You are a " + ", ".join(complements)
```

Furthermore, `raw_input` is a function. It must be called as such: `raw_input()`. Otherwise, you just create an alias of the function which you named `input`. You would still have to call it by appending `()` to it in order to receive the user input.

I also don't understand your `if var in input:` statement. `var` is a sentence you made, why would you search it in the user input? It would be clearer to do `if raw_input() in complements`, or something along the lines of it.

If you are beginning to learn Python, I would recommend you to use Python 3 instead of Python 2. `raw_input()` was renamed `input()` in Python 3.